# use ghost script to extract single spot color

Tags: ghostscript

I am trying to use ghostscript to extract the image for a single spot color (from a PDF), REGARDLESS of whether it would be visible when printed.

I tried using the tiffsep device, but the problem is that any of the spot color that is hidden by objects above does not get sent out.

Is there any device, or settings that would allow simply any objects regardless of visibility to be extracted to a bitmap file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object overlies another in PostScript then it is absolutely correct that it causes the underlying object not to render in that position (modulo overprint) because PostScript has an opaque imaging model.

So no, you can't prevent this, its supposed to work like that.